# How to refresh DataGrid's ItemsSource automatically after changed?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I don't understand why my ItemsSource don't auto change but when the `dialog` that is holding the `DataGrid` is called again, it changed.

This is my `ViewModel`:

```
public ObservableCollection<Student> Students { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Student>();


private RelayCommand<ObservableCollection<Student>> _getStudents;

//this is my list getter 
public RelayCommand<ObservableCollection<Student>> GetStudents
{
    get
    {
        return _getStudents
        ?? (_getStudents= new RelayCommand<ObservableCollection<Student>>(DoGetStudents));
    }
}

public void DoGetStudents(ObservableCollection<Student> students)
{
    Students = new ObservableCollection<Student>();

    var studs = _myService.GetStudents();

    foreach (var item in studs)
    {
        Students.Add(item);
    }
}


// adding function but not auto refresh
private async void DoAddStudent()
{
    await _myService.AddStudent(Student);
    DoGetStudents.Execute(null);
}
```

Eventhough `DoGetStudents.Execute(null);` line got called after adding, the `DataGrid` in the dialog don't refresh unless I reopen the dialog. What could I be missing?

Comment: Students property needs to notify about the change. Your collection notifies about items not about being assigned i.e. `Students = new ObservableCollection<Student>();` Doesn't notify. Put a backing field and call OnPropertyChanged

Comment: Or instead of creating new list every time, call clear and add items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the property to a new `ObservableCollection<Student>`, you should also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event from the setter of `Students`.

But instead of doing this, you can reuse the same collection and just clear it when the command executes:

```
public void DoGetStudents(ObservableCollection<Student> students)
{
    Students.Clear();

    var studs = _myService.GetStudents();

    foreach (var item in studs)
    {
        Students.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you don't really need an `ObservableCollection<T>` in the first place.